# Nashorn does not find function when eval with bindings

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn, scriptengine

There is a strange difference when I evaluate a nashorn script with or without bindings: without bindings there is no problem invoking a function, but with the bindings the function is not found. Here is an example:

```
public class SimpleNashornTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
        ScriptEngine jsEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        Compilable jsCompilable = (Compilable) jsEngine;
        Invocable jsInvocable = (Invocable) jsEngine;

        ScriptContext scriptCtxt = new SimpleScriptContext();
        Bindings engineScope = scriptCtxt.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
        CompiledScript jsScript = jsCompilable.compile("function definition() {print(\"Hello\")}");
        jsScript.eval(engineScope); // no error with jsScript.eval() !
        jsInvocable.invokeFunction("definition", new Object[] {});
    }
}
```

This yields the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such function definition
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror.callMember(ScriptObjectMirror.java:204)
```

Without the parameter engineScope in the evaluation of the script the function is found and invoked. Can anybody explain this difference? How can I use bindings without getting an error?

Comment: What happens if you pass `engineScope` as the second parameter to `invokeFunction`?

Comment: If the bindings are set as second argument in the invoke, it is passed as argument to the javascript function, but this is not what was intended. I want to set a global variable. As an example refer to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/ on multiple scopes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a new ScriptContext and it's associated `ENGINE_SCOPE` Bindings to compile the script. `invokeFunction`/`invokeMethod` use the default ScriptContext (and it's associated `ENGINE_SCOPE` Bindings) to search the function. Each different `ENGINE_SCOPE` Bindings is associated with its own ECMAScript global object (and it's own ECMAScript global objects).

So, you can fix your program by

1. changing the default context to be the new context before invoke:

   ```
   // change the default ScriptContext
   jsEngine.setContext(scriptCtxt);
   jsInvocable.invokeFunction("definition", new Object[] {});
   ```
2. Use the default ScriptContext for compiled script as well. As in:

   ```
   ScriptContext scriptCtxt = jsEngine.getContext(); // new SimpleScriptContext();
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes sense. There is only one thing: you have to set the context before the evaluation of the script. So I placed jsEngine.setContext(scriptCtxt) before the eval. If you place it before the invoke you get the same error as before. As to whether prefer your solution 1 or 2, I would take 1, if this allows me to reuse the compiled script, even concurrently in different threads.